# How cast a WrappedArray[WrappedArray[(String, String)]] to Array[String] in Spark (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Good,

I'm working with the spark framework in Scala. My dataframe has a column with the following structure and content:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Email_Code                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray([3,spain]), WrappedArray([,]), WrappedArray([3,spain])]                        |
|[WrappedArray([3,spain]), WrappedArray([3,spain])]                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

|-- Email_Code: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Value: string (nullable = true)
```

And I am trying to develop a udf function that takes all the values ​​of the "Code" structure present in the array. But I'm not able ...

I would like an exit like the following:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Email_Code                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[3,,3]                                                                                       |
|[3,3]                                                                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I got to fix it:

```
val transformation = udf((data: Seq[Seq[Row]]) => {data.flatMap(x => x).map{case Row(code:String, value:String) => code}})

df.withColumn("result", transformation($"columnName"))
```

Comment: You may encounter match errors as you map non exhaustive case. Use `collect` instead that takes function combining a filter and map. `val udf = (data: Seq[Seq[Row]]) => {data flatMap identity collect{ case Row(code:String, value:String) => code} }`